# What is the difference between Gaussian White noise and $iid$ noise and how can I check?

Tags: statistics, correlation, independence, time-series, noise

If I understand correctly, a series {$X_t$} is $iid$ noise if there is no trend or seasonal component and the observations {$x_t$} are independent and identically distributed with zero mean, while a series {$X_t$} is Gaussian White noise if it is a sequence of uncorrelated, i.e. $\rho(X_i,X_j)=0$, where each $X_i$ has zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. But how can it be that every $IID(0,\sigma^2)$ sequence is also a $WN(0,\sigma^2)$ sequence, but the converse is not true (independence vs uncorrelated)? And can someone please name some tests that should I use when checking for if a 1000x1 vector time series is just White noise or also $iid$ noise? Thanks!

Comment: A white noise is any $iid$ sequence of random variables (sometimes you also ask that it is  zero-mean and/or has a well-defined/finite variance), a Gaussian white noise is the same where each random variable is normally distributed.

Comment: And sorry : by extension, in signal processing, we also say to be white noise any sequence of r.v. which is uncorrelated and stationary instead of fully independent, because this property stays true under any unitary linear operator (as the Fourier transform..).

Comment: But my textbook states that every $iid$ sequence is also White noise, but the reverse is not always true. Aren't you stating the opposite?

Comment: Yes, I told you it depends on textbooks. In signal processing....

Comment: Ok, thanks! The textbook I have does not include fourier so I think I have to use both correlation and independence..

Comment: I guess it states that any sequence of r.v. which is uncorrelated and zero-mean and with constant variance is white noise ? maybe it also asks that each r.v. is identically distributed (but not independent, only uncorrelated..)

Comment: yes, it says: uncorrelated and zero-mean and with constant variance is white noise, but requires nothing regarding identical distribution. Do you know any tests I can use to see if a vector is only White Noise or also IID?

Comment: see if $\mathbb{E}[ |X_n|^2 ] = \sigma^2$ for every $n$, $\mathbb{E}[ X_n ] = 0$, and $\mathbb{E}[ X_n X_m ] =0$ for every $ n \ne m$  (if the r.v. are complex : $\mathbb{E}[ X_n \overline{X_m} ] = 0$). and to see if the r.v. are independent, you have to check if $P(X_n | X_m) = P(X_n)$ for every $n \ne m$..

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking something similar but this is better!

Comment: now the interesting part : can you prove that if $(X_n)_{n \in 1 \ldots N}$ is white noise, then any unitary/orthonormal transformation of the random vector $X = [X_1, \ldots,X_N]$ is also white noise ?

Comment: Would it be that it is so because of the independence of time during the transform..?

Comment: if $M$ is an orthonormal matrix then $M^T M = M M^T = I$  i.e. with $M_i$ the rows of $M$  : $M_i M_i^T = \|M_i\|^2=1$ and $ M_j M_i^T= 0$ whenever $i \ne j$. hence with $Y = M X$ :  $Y_i = M_i X = \sum_{j=1}^N M_{i,j} X_j$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y_a Y_b] = \mathbb{E}[\left(\sum_{j=1}^N M_{a,j} X_j\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^N M_{b,j} X_j\right)] = \sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{i=1}^N M_{b,j} M_{a,i}\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] = \sum_{j=1}^N M_{b,j} M_{a,j}\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] = \sigma^2 M_a^T M_b $ which is $0$ whenever $a \ne b$, and $\sigma^2$ whenever $a=b$, i.e. $(Y_n)$ is white noise